# (General) When can you change the order of integration in a double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Under what conditions does the following statement hold?

$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(y,x)\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy, \text{ or }\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}f(y,x)\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

The upper and lower bounds could be different for all I know, but I just left them the same because I didn't know what else to do with them. The example I have in mind is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^x(e^x+e^y)}\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^y(e^x+e^y)}\ \mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

Both equalling $1/2$.

Comment: See [Fubini's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) theorem.

Answer (score 1):

When you change $f(x,y)$ to $f(y,x)$, you've done more than change the order of integration, you've actually changed the *variables* of integration.

This is easier to see if you do the change of variables in a few steps:

Given: $$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy$$, let $u=x$ and $v=y$. Then,

- $dxdy = dudv$,
- $f(x,y)=f(u,v)$
- if $y=a$ then $v=a$, and if $y=b$, then $v=b$
- if $x=c$ then $u=c$, and if $x=d$, then $u=d$
  So we get:
  $$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(u,v)dudv$$

Now, we do another substitution: this time, $y=u$ and $x=v$:

- $dudv = dydx$,
- $f(u,v)=f(y,x)$
- if $v=a$ then $x=a$, and if $v=b$, then $z=b$
- if $u=c$ then $y=c$, and if $u=d$, then $y=d$
  So:
  $$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(y,x)dydx$$

---

Back to the original integral:

$$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dxdy$$

That means

$$\int_a^b\left[\int_c^d f(x,y)dx\right]dy$$

Changing the *order* of integration *in this example* is trivial: just swap the integrals, and swap the infinitesimals:

$$\int_a^b\left[\int_c^d f(x,y)dx\right]dy=\int_c^d\left[\int_a^b f(x,y)dy\right]dx$$

In general, you have to mess with the bounds of the integrals in more complex ways.

For your specific question:

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac1{e^x(e^x+e^y)}dxdy=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac1{e^y(e^x+e^y)}dxdy$$ not just because of changing the order of integration (which won't change the function being integrated), but because you've changed also variables, substituting $(y,x)$ for $(x,y)$